# transition effect on element A while hovering element B

Tags: html, css, sass

I am struggling to get a transition on the .blue div, while hovering the parent - .red div.

What I want to achieve is a slow transition, say 1s from display: none, to block.

The stylesheet is in SCSS and is nested. Can someone please help me out?

[Codepen fiddle](https://codepen.io/patryk-byszek/pen/WNEXbKR)

HTML:

```
<div class='app'>
  <div class='red'>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.app {
  heigh: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .red {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 30rem;
    width: 30rem;
    &:hover {
      .blue {
        display: block;
      }
    }
    .blue {
      display: none;
      height: 10rem;
      width: 10rem;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: blue;
      // transition: 1s; DOESNT WORK
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .red {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 30rem;
    width: 30rem;
    &:hover {
      .blue {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    .blue {
      opacity: 0; //add opacity
      height: 10rem;
      width: 10rem;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: 1s;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You missed the important part in your answer tho. The reason it doesn't work with display is because `transition` has a set of properties that you can use it on. Check out the [list of animated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Comment: Also `opacity` is not neccessarily the best practice, because you might not want the element to exist in the DOM. You should use `max-width` instead which still doesn't remove the element from the DOM, but you cannot interact with it anymore since it has no clickable space left.

Comment: @kmp transition doesn't work with display, so you need to use other css properties alognwith opacity. If the requirement is to not have element in the dom to interact, then scale(0) would work or setting height 0.

Comment: `...the reason it doesn't work with display is because transition has a set of properties that you can use it on.` Maybe read my comment carefully next time

Comment: @kmp you are fee to post your answer without opacity & just "transition set of properties"